# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't boot, only boot in recovery mode

Tags: 16.04, boot, dual-boot, intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with windows 10 but Ubuntu only boots in recovery mode.

After googling it seems that problem is Intel graphics drivers. I tried several solutions from other people with same problem but none worked.

I'm new at Ubuntu.

Can someone help, please?

Comment: Which solutions did you try?  Did they involve adding the word "nomodeset" to the grub line starting with "linux"?  Intel's hardly ever a problem, do you have other video hardware like Nvidia?

Comment: @ubfan1 - Thanks for the answer. Yes, I already tried to add "nomodeset", I tried Boot repair and I tried to install older drivers but nothing resulted. I'll keep looking. Thanks